# What quantity can a microstate have?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, chemical-potential

I confused whether a microstate's chemistry potential is defined.
And how about temperature, pressure, entropy?

And what is a microstate? A ensemble contain a set of microstates. The microstate is a phase point in phase space in classical mechanic? The microstate is a set of quantum number in quantum mechanic?

Answer (score 1):

A *microstate* is defined as a specific microscopic configuration that a system can have. One of the primary goals of statistical physics is to see the relation between microscopic proprieties and macroscopic ones, i.e. how microscopic constituents are built together to make macroscopic states.

Each time you think about microstates you can think of them simply as classical systems so they have any propriety that a classical system has, for example, energy. Proprieties like temperature or entropy cannot be associated with a single microstate.

An example that cleared my mind is the argument of Robert ZWANZIG where he derived the langevin equation in a deductive way.

Comment: But if a microstate don't have temperature, how can we define the NVT ensemble?
microscopic configuration isn't a phase point?
I really confused T_T

Comment: @zjsun a microscopic configuration can be a phase point. But those can't have temperature. To define the NVT Ensemble, you fix N and V and then require all the possible phase points to have a probability density, so that the energy EXPECTATION VALUE is fixed. The equilibrium Macrostate of the NVT is then the state of maximum entropy.

Comment: @Quantumwhisp So the thermodynamic properties are not ensemble average over the microstates? A single microstate only have mechanics properties? NVT ensemble don't mean a set of microstates satisfy {$N_v = N, V_v=V, T_v=T$}, but a set of shots for the macrostate?

Comment: @zjsun NVT ensemble means EVERY microstate with probability >0 has the same N and the same V (alternatively, if your phase space only contains the 2N phase space coordinates, you don't treat N and V as observables at all, but as parameters instead). It also means that the energy EXPECTATION VALUE for all microstates (weighted with their probabilities) is some fixed quantity. 1/T then is the derivation of the (maximized) entropy with respect to the energy expectation value. Because S(<E>) is convex, T can parameterise all possible macro states (=probability density for the micro state).